# Customize or lower the requested Permissions for apps in MacOS

Tags: macos, applications, permission, settings

In MacOS Settings' "Privacy & Security" panel, is it possible to reduce/lower the approved privileges/capabilities of apps? Or to modify or add custom capabilities to apps, different from what the app explicitly requested?

For example,

- in case some app requested to access the Documents folder, approved and shown in the "*Files and Folders*" privilege, is it possible to change the folder path to something else later? (for example, to change it to a more-specific/deeper sub-folder inside Documents)?
- to add Microphone access even if not explicitly requested by app? or if requested in the past without approval, deciding to approve later?
- to lower/reduce a "*Full Disk Access*" privilege into the (more specific and restricting) Files and Folders with specific folder paths? (in case I know in advance that it's fine for the app's logic and behavior)